# reverse and print an array using recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, reverse

the method below works fine, but I can't find a way to print the reversed array using same method. I tried for-each loop but it print three arrays not just one.
for example if the inputs:

> size 5, start=1, end=5, arr[] ={1,2,3,4,5}

output:

> 543215432154321

correct output should be

> 54321

**here is the code:**

```
static void reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        reverse(arr, start + 1, end - 1);       
    }   

    for (int pr : arr) {
        System.out.print(pr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your initial call be `start = 0` and `end = 4` since arrays index starting at zero? And your function prints the entire array on every call, so you are getting it output multiple times.

Comment: return the array as result and then in the calling method print the content in for loop

Comment: Because it executed n-times and prints the array n-times.

Comment: I figured that now, thank you.

Comment: If it's all working for you now, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are very very close.

The only mistake you are making is printing the result from inside the `reverse`  method - don't forget it's recursive so you'll get intermediate results printed.

Instead, call in first from another method, then print it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    reverse(arr,0,arr.length-1);
    for (int pr : arr) {
        System.out.print(pr);
    }
}

static void reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        reverse(arr, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second mistake of the OP's which you corrected but didn't mention is indexing the array originally from 0 to length-1 instead of 1 to length. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the array everytime it calls 'reverse' method . I have modified a bit of your code. And its working fine.

```
static void reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
    reverse(arr, start + 1, end - 1);       
    } 
    else {
     for (int pr : arr) {
        System.out.print(pr);
    }
```

Since size of your array is 5, you should be doing something like this

```
reverse (myArray,0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 //assume u have create an array;
    System.out.print("this array reversely equal to : ");
    ArrayReverse(array, 0);
}

public static void ArrayReverse(int[] a, int index) {

    if (index > a.length - 1) {
        return;
    }
    ArrayReverse(a, index + 1);
    System.out.print(a[index] + " ");

}
```